# jsonb join not working properly in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a query that joins on a jsonb type column in postgres that I want to convert to sqlalchemy in django using the aldjemy package

```sql
SELECT anon_1.key AS tag, count(anon_1.value ->> 'polarity') AS count_1, anon_1.value ->> 'polarity' AS anon_2
FROM  feedback f
         JOIN tagging t ON t.feedback_id = f.id
         JOIN jsonb_each(t.json_content -> 'entityMap') AS anon_3 ON true
         JOIN jsonb_each(((anon_3.value -> 'data') - 'selectionState') - 'segment') AS anon_1 ON true
where f.id = 2
GROUP BY anon_1.value ->> 'polarity', anon_1.key;
```

The json_content field stores data in the following format:

```json
{
  "entityMap":
  {
    "0":
    {
      "data":
      {
        "people":
        {
          "labelId": 5,
          "polarity": "positive"
        },
        "segment": "a small segment",
        "selectionState":
        {
          "focusKey": "9xrre",
          "hasFocus": true,
          "anchorKey": "9xrre",
          "isBackward": false,
          "focusOffset": 75,
          "anchorOffset": 3
        }
      },
      "type": "TAG",
      "mutability": "IMMUTABLE"
    },
    "1":
    {
      "data":
      {
        "product":
        {
          "labelId": 6,
          "polarity": "positive"
        },
        "segment": "another segment",
        "selectionState":
        {
          "focusKey": "9xrre",
          "hasFocus": true,
          "anchorKey": "9xrre",
          "isBackward": false,
          "focusOffset": 138,
          "anchorOffset": 79
        }
      },
      "type": "TAG",
      "mutability": "IMMUTABLE"
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the following sqlalchemy code to achieve the query

```py
first_alias = aliased(func.jsonb_each(Tagging.sa.json_content["entityMap"]))
print(first_alias)
second_alias = aliased(
    func.jsonb_each(
        first_alias.c.value.op("->")("data")
        .op("-")("selectionState")
        .op("-")("segment")
    )
)

polarity = second_alias.c.value.op("->>")("polarity")

p_tag = second_alias.c.key
_count = (
    Feedback.sa.query()
    .join(
        CampaignQuestion,
        CampaignQuestion.sa.question_id == Feedback.sa.question_id,
        isouter=True,
    )
    .join(Tagging)
    .join(first_alias, true())
    .join(second_alias, true())
    .filter(CampaignQuestion.sa.campaign_id == campaign_id)
    .with_entities(p_tag.label("p_tag"), func.count(polarity), polarity)
    .group_by(polarity, p_tag)
    .all()
)
print(_count)
```

but it is giving me a `NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression` error on accessing `first_alias.c`

the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/work/api/app/campaign/views.py", line 119, in results_p_tags
    d = campaign_service.get_p_tag_count_for_campaign_results(id)
  File "/home/work/api/app/campaign/services/campaign.py", line 177, in get_p_tag_count_for_campaign_results
    return campaign_selectors.get_p_tag_counts_for_campaign(campaign_id)
  File "/home/work/api/app/campaign/selectors.py", line 196, in get_p_tag_counts_for_campaign
    polarity = second_alias.c.value.op("->>")("polarity")
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1093, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 746, in columns
    self._populate_column_collection()
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1617, in _populate_column_collection
    self.element._generate_fromclause_column_proxies(self)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 703, in _generate_fromclause_column_proxies
    fromclause._columns._populate_separate_keys(
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1216, in _populate_separate_keys
    self._colset.update(c for k, c in self._collection)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1216, in <genexpr>
    self._colset.update(c for k, c in self._collection)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 434, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 831, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 434, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 75, in operate
    return o[0](self.expr, op, *(other + o[1:]), **kwargs)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 173, in _getitem_impl
    _unsupported_impl(expr, op, other, **kw)
  File "/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-FPSaTdE5-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 177, in _unsupported_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

PS: The sqlalchemy version I'm using for this is 1.4.6
I used the same sqlalchmy query expression before in a flask project using sqlalchemy version 1.3.22 and it was working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using `table_valued` functions as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data.html#tutorial-functions-table-valued),
and accessing the `ColumnCollection` of the function using indices instead of keys. Code is as follows:

```py
first_alias = func.jsonb_each(Tagging.sa.json_content["entityMap"]).table_valued(
        "key", "value"
    )
second_alias = func.jsonb_each(
        first_alias.c[1].op("->")("data").op("-")("selectionState").op("-")("segment")
    ).table_valued("key", "value")

polarity = second_alias.c[1].op("->>")("polarity")

p_tag = second_alias.c[0]
```